# How do I use caret for multivariate regression for regularized regression using glmnet library?

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet, lasso-regression

I'm trying to perform multivariate regression specifically Lasso and Elasticnet of about 500 independent variables on 215 response variables. I know it's possible to do multivariate regression using glmnet package with the argument family= "mgaussian" but how to do it with caret wrapper.
 Does caret not support the multiresponse model?

Below is my attempt at achieving this:

```
cctrl1 <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10,repeats=3, returnResamp="all",verboseIter = T,savePredictions = T)

EnetGrid <- expand.grid(alpha = seq(0,1,by=0.1),lambda = seq(0.001,0.1,by = 0.001))

set.seed(849)
enet_cv_model <- train(trainX, trainY, 
method = "glmnet", 
trControl = cctrl1,
metric = c("RMSE","Rsquared"),
family='mgaussian',
tuneGrid =EnetGrid)
```

This is the error message that I'm getting.

*Error: Error in check_dims(x = x, y = y) : nrow(x) == n is not TRUE*

Comment: What is the class of `trainY`?

Comment: It was data frame initially. I converted it into matrix and updated the error message.

Comment: Do you have a multiresponse model? Otherwise, trainY should be a vector

Comment: Yes. That's what I want to know. Does caret support a multiresponse model with 'glmnet' method?

Comment: Maybe set `family = "mgaussian"` in the trainControl?

Comment: I tried that as well but I'm getting the following error message.
_Error in trainControl(method = "repeatedcv", number = 10, repeats = 3, : unused argument (family = "mgaussian")_

Comment: Sorry, not the trainControl, the tune grid. If that doesn't work, I'm not sure caret will support multiresponse glmnet.